# Azure > App Service > Mobile App > Offline Sync doesn't work on my Android (Xamarin.Forms)

Tags: sqlite, azure, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

I'm currently struggeling to get Azure > App Service > Mobile App > Offline Sync running.
In my current experiment I'm trying to strictly follow the instruction.

So I did as follows:

**Iteration 1**

- Defined an App Service on Azure (with new DB etc.)
- Download the Quick Start C# backend VS solution
- Download the Quick Start Xamarin.Forms App
- Integrate the Xamarin.Forms PCL and Droid projects into the 1st solution

**=> Test: TodoList App works as expected. Cool!**

**Iteration 2**

- Added OFFLINE_SYNC_ENABLED to "Conditional compilation symbols" to the project properties
- Run the app again on my Nexus 5 (Android 6.0 - API 23)

**=> Pull async is called... but nothing happens. So my todoItems stored in the Azure DB do not appear.**

The only more or less interesting log i found is this line:
*02-23 09:39:55.280 I/mono-stdout(25706): Invalid sync operation: The request could not be completed. (Bad Request)*

I couldn't recognize any traffic via fiddler.

**For me it looks like the templates on azure wont work...**

Am I doing something wrong? Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks a lot!

**Additional facts:**

Now I found something interesting in the Log Stream:

https://offlinecheck1.azurewebsites.net/tables/TodoItem?$filter=(__updatedAt ge datetimeoffset'1970-01-01T00:00:00.0000000%2B00:00')&$orderby=__updatedAt&$skip=0&$top=50&__includeDeleted=true&__systemproperties=__updatedAt%2C__version%2C__deleted

This request doesn't work with PostMan eather.

If I manupulate this url by removing "__" before the 2 first ocurrencies of __updatedAt, I receive the for expected records.

Is there something wrong in the component which constructs the url?

Comment: What version of the SQLite store are you referencing?

Comment: 3.8.7.2 of SQLitePCL and SQLitePCL.Ext. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Since it's a bad request, the server is actually getting a request.  It's a good idea to turn on Diagnostics and look at tracing.  You can do this via [Visual Studio Debugging](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio/) or via the [Azure Portal](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log/)

Comment: On the azure Stream Log I found this Request which ends with a 400: GET https://offlinecheck1:80/tables/TodoItem?$filter=(__updatedAt%20ge%20datetimeoffset'1970-01-01T00%3A00%3A00.0000000%2B00%3A00')&$orderby=__updatedAt&$skip=0&$top=50&__includeDeleted=true&__systemproperties=__updatedAt%2C__version%2C__deleted
The message is:
The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax.
I was surprised about the domain...
Or could it be something with the ZUMO-API-VERSION header?

Comment: I should have been clearer, I'm wondering what version of the Mobile SDK SQLite store you're using. Is this what you're referencing? https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore/

Comment: No... "I am" using https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.MobileServices.SQLiteStore/
Looks similar but different.
You can easily reproduce my exsample in 5 minutes by following my steps. I didn't change anything on the azure quick start template.

Comment: Have you seen my "additional facts" in the description? strange isn't it? Thanks for your support.

Comment: Now I replaced the "WindowsAzure..." with mentioned "Microsoft.Azure..." package. Unfortunately this didn't fix the potentially wrong query.

Comment: Any other suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using an incompatible version of the Mobile client SDK and the server SDK. You should be using [Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client/2.0.0), **NOT** WindowsAzure.MobileServices.

For more information, see [Client and server SDK versioning](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-client-and-server-versioning/).

FYI, the change between Mobile Services and Mobile Apps is that now system properties do not have a double underscore prefix. This is documented in the [Upgrade from Mobile Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-net-upgrading-from-mobile-services/#updating-the-server-project) article.

Here's a completed version of the Xamarin.Forms offline sync sample for Mobile Apps: [Xamarin.Forms offline sync todo list](https://github.com/lindydonna/xamarin-forms-offline-sync).

Comment: Not anymore... as you can see in my comments above, I changed that. But it didn't change the behavior. The template I took from Azure / Mobile App / Settings / Quick start / Xamarin.Forms / 3 New App > Download. Funny is, that now it comes with the "right" version (which doesn't work either).

If you follow the steps in my original description, it will not work unless they fixed it. I tried it several times.

Comment: What do the outgoing requests look like now? If you are still seeing the underscores, you're still using the wrong client library.

Comment: It seems that MSFT is fixing the Quick Start Templates. By comparing my packages with those of newly downloaded quickstart projects I found some more differences.

Now I strictly use Microsoft.Azure* instead of WindowsAzure.* packages. The GET request works now as expected.

But the next problem occurs on the POST action. Similar to the first issue there is an exception **"Could not find member '__version' on object of type 'TodoItem'..."**

Comment: I started from scratch with a new solution (create app service > quickstart c# server > quickstart xamarin.forms project > install package azure-sqlite > add OFFLINE_SYNC_ENABLED to compilation symbols. **pull works now. but the pushAsync fails.**

Comment: We haven't changed the quickstart solution recently, so I'm surprised that you're seeing a difference. I recently created a sample for offline sync on Xamarin Forms, so give this a try: https://github.com/lindydonna/xamarin-forms-offline-sync

Comment: I gave your sample a try. It worked. I did the mistake that I didn't change the SQLiteStore file name. Now my Sample works as well. So far I'm happy now. But I still can't imagine that there was no change on the quick start templates. I would remember if I have had replaced the installed nuget packages with old WindowsAzure packages. Thanks for your help!

Comment: FYI, if you added the wrong SQLiteStore package to your protect, it would have uninstalled the new client package and installed the old one. That might have been what happened.